# What's wrong with this slice call in JS?

Tags: javascript, css, slice

I write this line but get an error in response:

> slice can't process there.

Why and how do I fix that?

```
function (row) {
    var r = Math.round(Object.values(row)[3] / Object.values(row)[4]);
    var t = Object.values(row)[2];
    var s = Math.round((t - r) / t * 100);
    return '<span id="up">${s.slice(0,2)}%</span>'
}
```

Comment: `slice` isn't a method on numbers, it's a method on *arrays* or *strings*. `Math.round` returns a number.

Comment: please add `row` and the wanted result.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, so what if I want to separate numbers from the return command

Comment: @borneo - I don't know what you mean by "separate the numbers." If you want to use `slice`, convert from number to string (I'm guessing that's what you want, not an array).

Comment: does the `toString` method apply here?

Comment: `var u = toString(s)
                return '<span id="up">${u.slice(0,2)}%</span>'` but is output `[o%`

Comment: Perhaps you should use `s.toString()` instead of `toString(s)`...

Comment: But I doubt that your code will work correctly when 100% is reached though... So why do you want to get only the first two digits of the value of `s` in the first place? I think it's completely unnecessary. If the value of `s` will not reach 100, everything should be just fine as it is (I think). And if it can reach 100, you should probably regard those 3 digits as well (and not display `10%` instead of `100%`)...

Comment: in the line above I look for the difference in each number, and basically if the number is included in the percentage of the value of the movement, I think it is necessary to see what percentage of the number changes

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `s` is a number but the `slice` function requires a `string`. The solution would be to cast `s` into a string:

```
const slice = `${s}`.slice(0, 2);
```

**Edit**

To display a number with `n` decimals, you can multiply it by `10^n` before rounding and then dividing it by the same number, cutting of anything after `n` decimals.

```
// display number with n decimals
const numberDisplay = (number, numberOfDecimals) => Math.round(number * Math.pow(10, numberOfDecimals)) / Math.pow(10, numberOfDecimals);

// your desired number display
const slice = numberDisplay(s, 2);
```

Comment: that output is `-1;%`. i fill is `-1,00%`

Comment: Can you supply me with example values for `t` and `s` so I can figure out what you are trying to do, please? Your request was to fix `slice` error, which I did. You are talking about a logical error.

Comment: the value of `t` and s `is` a number with 8 digits behind, for example `4, 012301234`. I want to limit this value to 2 numbers behind. That is all

Comment: I have added your request to my answer

Comment: thanks for the pow function, i forgot about that. I will try the method you gave first.

Comment: If it works out for you I would be super happy if you marked my answer as "the answer". If not, I am happy to help. Thank you!